# Read embedded JSON-Object in a CSV-file via arangoimp

Tags: json, csv, arangodb, arangoimport

Having a CSV-File as follows (modeled from the IRIS data-set):

```
Species,values
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":5.1,""Sepal.Width"":3.5,""Petal.Length"":1.4,""Petal.Width"":0.2}"
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":4.9,""Sepal.Width"":3,""Petal.Length"":1.4,""Petal.Width"":0.2}"
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":4.7,""Sepal.Width"":3.2,""Petal.Length"":1.3,""Petal.Width"":0.2}"
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":4.6,""Sepal.Width"":3.1,""Petal.Length"":1.5,""Petal.Width"":0.2}"
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":5,""Sepal.Width"":3.6,""Petal.Length"":1.4,""Petal.Width"":0.2}"
setosa,"{""Sepal.Length"":5.4,""Sepal.Width"":3.9,""Petal.Length"":1.7,""Petal.Width"":0.4}"
```

How can i read the `values` column as object instead of string?

Using

```
arangoimp --file /Desktop/iris.csv --type csv --collection iris --create-collection true
```

This gives me two strings per row....

In the GUI i get:

[image]

Whereas this i what i try to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arangoimp only allows imporing csv or json but can not mix them.

The easiest way should converting your csv file into json format and then import it (see [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html#importing-json-encoded-data)).